# Rails form_for, having a text_field without a label (without using CSS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, label, form-for

I know this is easy enough just removing the f.label, but then it changes the positioning (ie, would have to add padding).

Is there a way to do this without styling?

I tried

```
f.label :example, ""
```

But that would still yield 'Example'

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Sure, I'll post a picture of what the issue is. http://i.imgur.com/GkvD6.png. As you can see there are 5 rows of the same form, and in this case it is just unnecessary to have the labels on every line (just the top one would be ideal). If I take out f.label from the bottom 4 rows of forms, it messes up the positioning. I'd like to be able to accomplish this without using styling, but if I must, so be it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It certainly is a BAD PRACTICE to do what you are asking.**

What I would do is,

1. Use headers (`<th></th>`) for the labels as the first row`(<tr></tr>)` in html and the remaining text_fields as subsequent rows.
2. Im sure that some kind of loop is generating that form, take out the
   label_tag from the loop and keep only the text_filed_tags inside
   the loop.

Comment: Well I tried that and it was decent, https://gist.github.com/2695714. Here's what it looks like now. Not sure why there is the grey background and dotted blue lines, thoughts? Check it here: http://i.imgur.com/hXC2c.png

Comment: Check your html source code to find out why those dotted lines turned up and please tell me why wouldnt you use CSS?. Please use CSS! Thanks!

Comment: ...wow, I amaze myself. Made that way too difficult. Thanks for the input @beck03076.